# App stopped responding in android

Tags: java, android

i am creating a simple android application, but when i run it, app stopped working(responding). i am attaching code of my application. please help me.
this is MainActivity.java

and this is play.java
     package com.example.guessit;

```
import java.util.Random;

import android.R.bool;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Play extends Activity{

EditText et;
Button bt;
int num;
int count = 0;
int min = 1;
int max = 100;

Random r = new Random();
int i1 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_play);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    final boolean is_guess = false; 
    num = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());

    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             while(is_guess == false) 
             {
              if(num > 100 && num < 0)
              {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new           AlertDialog.Builder(Play.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Wrong Input !!");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Please enter the number within the    limit 1 to 100");
                alertDialog.show();
              }
             else if(num > i1)
             {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Entered number is greater than guessing number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                count++;
             }
             else if(num < i1)
             {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Entered number is smaller than guessing number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    count++;
             }
             else if(num == i1)
             {
                 count++;
                 AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Play.this).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Congratulations ");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("You Win\n");
                    Log.d("Total", "Attempt = "+count);
                    alertDialog.show();
             }
           }
        }
    });
 }


}
```

whenever i run this app, it run correctly but when i click to button to go to play.xml and play.java activity, it go. but after 2 or 3 sec. it stopped working.
please help.

Comment: Check your console, or logcat, and tell us what is the error that you are facing.

Comment: Too few code for understanding your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be having NumberFormatException due to this line:

```
num = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
```

You are fetching editText value to early, doing like this you will always get a empty string which cannot be converted to a number. What you need to do is to fetch value from editText only when user enters some value and clicks the button. So just follow the below code. Hope its help!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_play);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    final boolean is_guess = false;

    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int num = 0;
        try {
            num = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            num = 0;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
             while(is_guess == false) 
             {
              if(num > 100 && num < 0)
              {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new           AlertDialog.Builder(Play.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Wrong Input !!");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Please enter the number within the    limit 1 to 100");
                alertDialog.show();
              }
             else if(num > i1)
             {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Entered number is greater than guessing number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                count++;
             }
             else if(num < i1)
             {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Entered number is smaller than guessing number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    count++;
             }
             else if(num == i1)
             {
                 count++;
                 AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Play.this).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Congratulations ");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("You Win\n");
                    Log.d("Total", "Attempt = "+count);
                    alertDialog.show();
             }
           }
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: now play.xml is opening by clicking button. but when i enter number to edittext , and then click to check. it stopped responding

Comment: i add exception , but whenever i enter number in textbox and hit button, it get freeze and after sometime it stopped responding. please help.

Comment: I think there's something wrong in your while loop, its running infinitely. You need to make make 'is_guess = true' somewhere in the loop else it will  keep on iterating and hence your application will stop responding.

Comment: i tried this, but still not working.

Comment: can you please provide logcat output?

Comment: this is logcat-                                                                                                              03-09 05:54:06.730: D/gralloc_goldfish(1043): Emulator without       GPU emulation detected.
        03-09 05:54:11.502: I/System.out(1043): Could not parse java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
        03-09 05:54:12.210: D/dalvikvm(1043): GC_CONCURRENT freed 115K, 9% free 2664K/2900K, paused 73ms+66ms, total 486ms
        03-09 05:54:21.780: D/dalvikvm(1043): GC_CONCURRENT freed 261K, 12% free 2806K/3188K, paused 74ms+100ms, total 325ms

Comment: `num = 0;<br/>
 try {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "testing in text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
       String no = et.getText().toString();                                      
       if(no==null)
       {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "string is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
       }
         num = Integer.parseInt(no); 
      } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
         System.out.println("Could not parse " + e);
      }`

Answer (score 0):

Pls add logcat to your Question to help you better , any way it seems you define only 1 btn in your xml and want to find 3 btn in your activity class !

```
play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
help = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
about = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
```

define button2 and button3 in your XML and see the result

Comment: i already defined 2 more buttons in MainActivity.xml

Comment: this is logcat- `03-09 05:54:06.730: D/gralloc_goldfish(1043): Emulator without GPU emulation detected. 03-09 05:54:11.502: I/System.out(1043): Could not parse java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "" 03-09 05:54:12.210: D/dalvikvm(1043): GC_CONCURRENT freed 115K, 9% free 2664K/2900K, paused 73ms+66ms, total 486ms 03-09 05:54:21.780: D/dalvikvm(1043): GC_CONCURRENT freed 261K, 12% free 2806K/3188K, paused 74ms+100ms, total 325ms`